# how can i leave windows and go too linux?

Tags: java, linux, open-source

i am a java developer.
i used windows OS in all versions for years, and now i'm using windows 7
how can i leave windows and go to linux and not working like a very Beginner user.
i dont know the path exactly. and i dont like to close my hands in the new OS.
which version edition should i use and why ?
should i start from the command or the graphic is suitible for starting ?

Comment: More of a Windows -> Linux migration, SU?

Comment: contactless not...swipe again please

Comment: This more of a superuser question.  I think it's a real question, and I think it deserves an answer.  But this isn't the right forum.  Now if you had a more specific, clearly programming related question about moving from one platform to another, that would belong here.

Comment: @Petar Minchev - I think the OP is saying that (s)he feels like a beginning user on Linux, and wants a way to migrate so that feeling is minimized.

Comment: Practical suggestion: install SUN VirtualBox -> install Ubuntu inside a VM

Comment: @Omnifarious Maybe you are right. The question is too vague for me:)

Comment: because every body is ready to pay money of a begginer linux user and the are living free ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote Nike, "Just do it". Install Linux on your box, dual boot if you still want the Windows lifeline. Nothing will make you learn faster and more completely than honest to god necessity.

Comment: It's always necessary to move to a Windows alternative.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you install Ubuntu. Run in graphical mode. You will have access to a very powerful command line when you want it, and a nice command like when you want it. You will want graphical mode to run eclipse/intelliJ in most likely anyway....